# match multiple columns from gzip files

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to match multiple columns between file1.txt and file2.gz without unzipping file2.

```
file 1.txt:
1       11710779        -
1       12919623        CC


file2.gz:

1       13380   .       C       G       7829.15 VQSRTrancheSNP99.60to99.80      AC=30;AC_AFR=14;AC_AMR=1;AC_Adj=15;AC_EAS=0;AC_FIN=0
1       13382   .       C       G       320.40  VQSRTrancheSNP99.60to99.80      AC=3;AC_AFR=0;AC_AMR=0;AC_Adj=1;AC_EAS=0;AC_FIN=0;AC
1
```

I want to match $1,$2,3 in file1.txt with $1,$2,$4 in file.gz and return all lines in file2.

I tried

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2$4]++;next};c[$1$2$3] > 0' file2.gz file1.txt
```

and

```
 awk -F '\t'  'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3]++;next} (a[$1,$2,$4])' file1.txt file2.gz
```

Both commands did not work. Contents in file1 exist in file2 when I grep some of them individually. 
I'm not sure if I need to unzip file2 first before running the command. I can't unzip the file as it's too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zcat file2.txt.gz | awk -F '\t'  'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3]++;next} a[$1,$2,$4]' file1.txt -
```

The two file arguments to awk are `file1.txt` and  `-`.  The second file, `-`, tells awk to read from stdin where we have piped in `file2.txt.gz`

#### Example

Let's consider these two sample files:

```
$ cat file1.txt
1       11710779        -
1       12919623        CC
1       13382   C
```

And:

```
$ zcat file2.txt.gz
1       13380   .       C       G       7829.15 VQSRTrancheSNP99.60to99.80      AC=30;AC_AFR=14;AC_AMR=1;AC_Adj=15;AC_EAS=0;AC_FIN=0
1       13382   .       C       G       320.40  VQSRTrancheSNP99.60to99.80      AC=3;AC_AFR=0;AC_AMR=0;AC_Adj=1;AC_EAS=0;AC_FIN=0;AC
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ zcat file2.txt.gz | awk -F '\t'  'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3]++;next} a[$1,$2,$4]' file1.txt -
1       13382   .       C       G       320.40  VQSRTrancheSNP99.60to99.80      AC=3;AC_AFR=0;AC_AMR=0;AC_Adj=1;AC_EAS=0;AC_FIN=0;AC
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I run similar command before but I didn't put the standin '-' at the back. Now it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
$ cat > test.in
1 2
3 4
$ gzip test.in
$ awk '{print $1}' <(gunzip -c test.in.gz)
1
3
```